# SQL Azure Failover Grace Period what does it mean

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Reading the documentation, its a little confusing when a failover is triggered by MS. It states in the documentation

> By default, a failover group is configured with an automatic failover
> policy. The system triggers a geo-failover after the failure is
> detected and the grace period has expired

**The Setup**

- I have two SQL instances in EUN and EUW
- Failover Group configured thus I have a primary and secondary connection
- I have an API that uses the primary failover connection string

**Scenario**
An outage occurs in EUN (the primary). My API is using the primary failover connection (currently pointing to EUN). Does this mean my API is going to fail to connect to SQL until MS decide to do the failover which could be an hour? I guess this can be expedited with a forced manual failover.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent data loss synchronous replication should be in place and is not supported on automatic failover groups. With the GracePeriodWithDataLossHours you can control how long the system waits before initiating a forced failover, which may result in data loss. If the outage is recoverable within the specified time, then you don’t failover over and therefore avoid the data loss. If you perform some tests, you may see that a maximum three (3) seconds worth of transactions is lost every time a failover occurs.

During the grace period your application cannot connect unless you manually initiate a failover and accept the data loss.

To protect critical transactions from data loss, an application developer can call the [sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-wait-for-database-copy-sync-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) stored procedure immediately after committing the transaction. However, forced synchronization impacts performance because it blocks the calling thread until all committed transactions are replicated.